# Post on friend's wall using PHP SDK for Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to post on my friend's wall using PHP SDK of FB. The code publishes the post on my wall only and also not visible to others.

Here is the code:

```
$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',array(
            'link' => 'www.google.com',
            'message' => 'message','description' => "I am bond",
            'to' => array('id' => 'friend_id','name' => 'friend_name'),
            'actions' => array('name' => 'Re-share',
            'link' =>'http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/'),
            'privacy' => array('value' => 'EVERYONE')));
```

This code publishes on my wall rather than the friend's wall. Also the post is only visible to me and not to any one else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/me/feed`

That's you.

`/myFriendsNameHere/feed`

That's your friend.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Specifically the first sentence under "Publishing" where it shows you exactly how to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not able to post the links. Moreover its not visible to the friend and only i can see the post

Answer (score 1):

To post on a friends wall do an HTTP POST to /friendID/feed instead of /me/feed (which will post to your wall).  Also, remove the 'to' parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $friends = $facebook->api('me/friends');

    //print_r($friends['data']);
    print_r("Number of friends: ". count($friends['data']));

    foreach ($friends['data'] as $key=>$friendList) {
        echo "<br/>".$key." ".$friendList['name']."<img src='https://graph.facebook.com/".$friendList['id']."/picture' width='50' height='50' title='".$friendList['name']."' />";     
    }
```